# Деепричастие от глагола "ехать"

Tags: словообразование

Как-то попалось в одном обсуждении: люди спорили о том, можно ли сказать "едя". И вообще, реально ли образовать деепричастие от глагола "ехать"?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 5):

При образовании деепричастий несовершенного вида существуют фонетические ограничения, то есть от ряда глаголов такие деепричастия не образуются, что в данном случае относится к глаголу "ехать".
Образование деепричастий должно происходить по схеме: видеть - видит - видя, но для глагола "ехать" форма "едя" считается неблагозвучной и не применяется.

Тогда можно обратиться к дополнительным  способам образования. Ряд глаголов образуют деепричастия от основы настоящего времени с помощью суффиксов УЧИ/ЮЧИ (играючи, крадучись), а также от основы прошедшего времени  с помощью суффикса ВШИ (не знавши), но эти формы являются разговорными.

Однако для глагола "ехать" и разговорные варианты хороши, в результате чего мы имеем деепричастия  "едучи, ехав, ехавши", например: Не хвались, ЕДУЧИ на рать.ЕДУЧИ в город на бежевой «Волге», Дима размышлял о своей собачьей жизни (тот самый Дима, из "Берегись автомобиля").Я сам-то, еще ЕХАВ сюда, на вас же рассчитывал, что вы мне тоже скажете чего-нибудь новенького. ЕХАВШИ как-то из деревни в Москву, я остановился дни на два в одном губернском городе.

Остается выяснить стиль этих выражений. В словарях без особых пометок указывают варианты "едучи и ехав".

Answer (score 0):

При образовании деепричастий(да и причастий тоже)иногда теория расходится с практикой. У нас,получается, оптимальный вариант - едучи.

Answer (score 0):

Я понимаю тех, кто считает, что нормативных деепричастий нет.

Бесприставочные глаголы обычно регулярно не имеют деепричастий. Большинство же имеющихся считаются или устаревшими, или окказиональными.

Ехать - один из таких глаголов, к тому же с усеченной собственной словообразовательной парадигмой.

"Едучи" - форма устаревшая. "Ехав" - сомнительная, поскольку используется образец для образования причастий от глаголов совершенного вида.

Но из двух я бы предпочел все-таки "едучи", здесь хоть пусть и устаревшая, но правильная грамматика.

Answer (score -1):

1. Едучи
2. Ехав
   Это единственные возможные деепричастия.

Comment: Оба варианта сомнительны. "Едучи" - форма, сделанная по устаревшему шаблону, а "ехав" по шаблону, который обычно не используется для бесприставочных глаголов несовершенного вида.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?